# Как можно ускорить прибавление текста к переменной?

Tags: golang

1 мой способ:

```
text := "Количество юзеров: " + data.Count
if data.Chats > 0 {
   text += `\nЧатов: ` + data.Chats
}
if data.Online > 0 {
    text += `\nПользователей онлайн: ` + data.Online
}
```

2 способ:

```
text := ""
items := [...]string{
    "Количество юзеров: " + data.Count,
    `\nЧатов: ` + data.Chats,
    `\nПользователей онлайн: ` + data.Online
}
for _, i := range items {
    text += i
}
```

Посчитав время через time.Since, для меня 2ms - очень долго. Можно ли что-то сделать лучше, но чтобы выдавало результат менее чем за 2ms?

Comment: Может попробовать https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Builder?

Comment: спасибо посмотрю

Comment: strings.Builder как раз был создан для этого.

Comment: 11ms стало(((((

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`time.Since` - это неудачный вариант для оценки производительности. Если вам хочется узнать, сколько времени занимает операция, используйте [`Benchmark`](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#hdr-Benchmarks). Тогда вы бы узнали, что
а) время конкатенации измеряется не миллисекундами, а долями микросекунды, и
б) `strings.Builder` даёт самый быстрый вариант.

Вот пример оценки производительности различных способов форматирования строки: сложение строк, `strings.Join`, `strings.Builder`, `fmt.Sprintf`

```
package try

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "testing"
)

type Data struct {
    Count  int
    Chats  int
    Online int
}

var data = Data{Count: 10, Chats: 11, Online: 12}

func BenchmarkAdd(b *testing.B) {

    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        text := "Количество юзеров: " + strconv.Itoa(data.Count)
        if data.Chats > 0 {
            text += `\nЧатов: ` + strconv.Itoa(data.Chats)
        }
        if data.Online > 0 {
            text += `\nПользователей онлайн: ` + strconv.Itoa(data.Online)
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkSliceSum(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        text := ""
        items := [...]string{
            "Количество юзеров: " + strconv.Itoa(data.Count),
            `\nЧатов: ` + strconv.Itoa(data.Chats),
            `\nПользователей онлайн: ` + strconv.Itoa(data.Online),
        }
        for _, i := range items {
            text += i
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkSliceSum2(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        text := ""
        items := [...]string{
            "Количество юзеров: ", strconv.Itoa(data.Count),
            `\nЧатов: `, strconv.Itoa(data.Chats),
            `\nПользователей онлайн: `, strconv.Itoa(data.Online),
        }
        for _, i := range items {
            text += i
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkJoin(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        items := []string{
            "Количество юзеров: ", strconv.Itoa(data.Count),
        }
        if data.Chats > 0 {
            items = append(items, `\nЧатов: `+strconv.Itoa(data.Chats))

        }
        if data.Online > 0 {
            items = append(items, `\nПользователей онлайн: `+strconv.Itoa(data.Online))
        }
        _ = strings.Join(items, "")
    }
}

func BenchmarkJoin2(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        items := []string{
            "Количество юзеров: ", strconv.Itoa(data.Count),
        }
        if data.Chats > 0 {
            items = append(items, `\nЧатов: `, strconv.Itoa(data.Chats))

        }
        if data.Online > 0 {
            items = append(items, `\nПользователей онлайн: `, strconv.Itoa(data.Online))
        }
        _ = strings.Join(items, "")
    }
}

func BenchmarkSprintf(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        var msg string
        if data.Chats > 0 && data.Online > 0 {
            msg = `Количество юзеров: %[1] d
Чатов: %[2] d
Пользователей онлайн: %[3] d`
        } else if data.Chats > 0 {
            msg = `Количество юзеров: %[1] d
Чатов: %[2] d`
        } else if data.Online > 0 {
            msg = `Количество юзеров: %[1] d
Пользователей онлайн: %[3] d`
        } else {
            msg = `Количество юзеров: %[1] d`
        }
        _ = fmt.Sprintf(msg, data.Count, data.Chats, data.Online)
    }
}

func BenchmarkBuilder(b *testing.B) {

    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        bldr := strings.Builder{}
        bldr.WriteString("Количество юзеров: ")
        bldr.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(data.Count))
        if data.Chats > 0 {
            bldr.WriteString(`\nЧатов: `)
            bldr.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(data.Chats))
        }
        if data.Online > 0 {
            bldr.WriteString(`\nПользователей онлайн: `)
            bldr.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(data.Online))
        }
        _ = bldr.String()
    }
}
```

Результат сравнения на AMD Ryzen 5 в  Windows 11:

```
PS> go test -bench . 
goos: windows
goarch: amd64
pkg: example.org/strings/try
cpu: AMD Ryzen 5 Microsoft Surface (R) Edition
BenchmarkAdd-8           4476718               262.4 ns/op
BenchmarkSliceSum-8      3336183               358.7 ns/op
BenchmarkSliceSum2-8     2795918               462.0 ns/op
BenchmarkJoin-8          2897539               411.0 ns/op
BenchmarkJoin2-8         2769693               448.0 ns/op
BenchmarkSprintf-8       1885899               635.0 ns/op
BenchmarkBuilder-8       4783755               246.7 ns/op
PASS
ok      example.org/strings/try 11.356s
```

Видно, что `strings.Builder` уделывает всех.

Comment: отличный ответ.