Как эффективно объединять строки в Go?
В Go строка является примитивным типом. Это означает, что она доступна только для чтения, и любая манипуляция с ней создаст новую строку.
Мне нужно много раз объединять строки, не зная длины результирующей строки, какой самый лучший способ сделать это?
Наивный способ был бы таким:
var s string
for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
    s += getShortStringFromSomewhere()
}


И опять какие-то бессмысленные переводы с возможным нарушением лицензии... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760757

@user7860670, не. Я имел ввиду общий случай конкотенации строк

Забавно, что там по ссылке специализированный билдер не сильно отстаёт от банального сложения строк. Так что думаю сложение уже неплохо оптимизировано видимо.

Вопрос уже закрыли, поэтому без подробностей. Самый быстрый вариант объединить много строк - собрать строки в []string и затем вызывать strings.Join: https://go.dev/play/p/HDlwd1QtT7R . При сложении 1000 строк размером 500-1500 байт этот способ в 6+ раз быстрее, чем strings.Builder и в сотни раз быстрее, чем s += getShortStringFromSomewhere()

@PakUula Погодите, но как же ваш вот этот ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1386681/260769 ? ))

@CrazyElf мой ответ, но для случая десяти строк. В случае 1000 строк strings Join в разы быстрее, так как он сначала проходит по массиву строк, считает необходимый размер и ОДИН раз аллоцирует буфер. strings Builder в случае тысячи строк несколько раз реаллоцирует буфер, а операция += реаллоцирует буфер КАЖДЫЙ раз. Отсюда и вывод: для тысячи строк дешевле собрать все строки в массив и затем сделать Join.

Можно сделать с помощью bytes.Buffer.

Просто создать пустой буффер...

...и добавлять в него строки.


Вот код:
package main

import (
    "bytes"
)

func main() {
    buf := bytes.NewBufferString("") // (1)

    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        _, err := buf.WriteString(getShortStringFromSomewhere()) // (2)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}

